# Stopping all code execution until condition is met (Unity C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've found a lot of info about coroutines trying to solve this issue (waitUntil(), while loops, different variations of yield, etc.) but my issue with them is either the rest of the code after it still get executed whether or not the code in the coroutine has finished yet or it loops infinitely and freezes the Unity editor. For example, the following code will print the debug message even though no button was pressed (all while the coroutine is still waiting for a button press to finish its block of code itself).

```
ChoiceButtons.enableButtons();
StartCoroutine(WaitUntilButtonPress());
UnityEngine.Debug.Log("It skipped it.");
ChoiceButtons.setButtonPressed(false);
ChoiceButtons.disableButtons();
```

I need to be able to stop *all* further code execution until a specific function returns true. Is there a specific function I've just missed that accomplishes this or a specific manner in which I have to set up the loop (maybe using something outlandish like a threading functions such as SpinWait.SpinUntil() ?). I'm honestly at a complete loss because it seems like something that would definitely have its own function within a coroutine but I just can't find anything

Comment: turn the method you're in into a coroutine (return value of `IEnumerator`) then call it with `StartCoroutine`, then in the code you've shown here, call `WaitUntilButtonPress()` without `StartCoroutine`

Comment: If @derHugo 's answer helped please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/405359)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) does **not** delay the method which is calling it via `StartCoroutine` itself! Otherwise your main thread would freeze and thus eliminate the entire purpose of Coroutines ;)

What you definitely do not want to do is as you frazed it "stop **all** code execution" since .. also this would freeze your main thread -> you wouldn't be able to press any button ;)

---

If you want to wait for the routine to finish you have two main options:

Either make the entire calling method a routine

```
public void YourOriginalMethod()
{
    StartCoroutine (YourMethodRoutine());
}

private IEnumerator YourMethodRoutine ()
{
    ChoiceButtons.enableButtons();
    // This executed the wait routine and wait for it to finish
    yield return WaitUntilButtonPress();

    ChoiceButtons.setButtonPressed(false);
    ChoiceButtons.disableButtons();
}
```

Or you can use a callback pattern and execute the callback after the waiting is done. Since I don't know your `WaitForButtonPress` here as dummy code

```
public void YourOriginalMethod()
{
    ChoiceButtons.enableButtons();

    // Start the routine and pass a callback what to do when done
    // here e.g. as lambda expression
    StartCoroutine (WaitUntilButtonPress(() =>
    {
        ChoiceButtons.setButtonPressed(false);
        ChoiceButtons.disableButtons();
    }));
}

private IEnumerator WaitUntilButtonPress (Action whenDone)
{
    // Whatever your routine is waiting for
    yield return new WaitUntil(()=>buttonPressed);

    whenDone?.Invoke();
}
```

Or the same but without lambda but a method instead

```
public void YourOriginalMethod()
{
    ChoiceButtons.enableButtons();

    // Start the routine and pass a callback what to do when done
    StartCoroutine (WaitUntilButtonPress(AfterButtonWasPressed));
}

private void AfterButtonWasPressed()
{
    ChoiceButtons.setButtonPressed(false);
    ChoiceButtons.disableButtons();
}

private IEnumerator WaitUntilButtonPress (Action whenDone)
{
    // Whatever your routine is waiting for
    yield return new WaitUntil(()=>buttonPressed);

    whenDone?.Invoke();
}
```

Comment: Nice, hopefully this helps.

Comment: Perhaps all code within the block of code the coroutine was put into would have been better phrasing. I put emphasis on the all since I found a lot of resources of stopping the coroutine but not anything outside of it despite my best efforts